# How to send mail from a custom UITableViewCell using MFMailComposerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to send mail while clicking a button in a custom `UITableViewCell` using `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Appreciate if answer is in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Following code in your .h file**

`#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>`

Give Delegate `<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>`

**Following code in your .m file**

```
//Where you want to open dialog write below code

if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailCont = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailCont.mailComposeDelegate = self; // Required to invoke mailComposeController when send

        [mailCont setSubject:@"Your Subject!"];
        [mailCont setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"hello@test.com"]];
        [mailCont setMessageBody:@"Your Body" isHTML:NO];

        [self presentViewController:mailCont animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

//Delegate Method

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            //YOUR ACTION
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            //YOUR ACTION
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            //YOUR ACTION
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            //YOUR ACTION
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

You can dismiss view by this code - `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are testing it in Real device not in simulator and you have a mail ID configured in your device

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@interface ViewController ()<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)sendmail:(id)sender {

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
            MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [mailer setSubject:@"Subject"];
            NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Recipients", nil];
            [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];
            NSString *emailBody = @"Body";
            [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
            [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{

    // Close the Mail Interface
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil]; will not work if call this from inside a custom uitableviewcell. How to do that?@manishsharma93

Comment: Present the controller in keywindow. Replace self for presenting and dismissing with [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController].

Comment: If this fulfil your requirement. Please do accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: Actually it doesn't fulfill mine because i have asked it in the context of implementing it from a custom tableviewcell class.